# how to end loading screen? c#, javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, loading

Below is a function to display a loading gif when the webpage loads or has a post back. It seems to work fine, but it doesn't go away after load. How can i make the loading function end when the page has loaded?

p.s. I have tried setting the visibility of the div to false on page_loadcomplete, but it comes up with a pool error.

Please let me know if you have any questions or i can clarify anything. 
thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
</script>

<!-- page loading div -->
 </div>
    <div class="loading" runat="server" id="pageLoader" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <img src="images/loadingGIF.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div tags are a part of your DOM, therefore you can remove them with Javascript. If you wish to hide ".loading", you can do it after the page has loaded by adding this event to your Javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
$(".loading").hide(); }
```

Comment if that's not what you are looking for.